# Trying to pass a JSON object to C# using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to pass a dynamic, user created object through AJAX to some C#. I'm not really experienced with JSON, but it seemed like a good method. I'm not sure why, but it's giving me an error on my declaration of the object. (Supposedly.) What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: It seems to only error in IE and but I need it to work in IE7.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MDDC; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Mar 2012 14:15:19 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 18
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:56560/Default.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('input[type=button').click(function(){

                var json_obj = { $('#t1').val() : $('#p1').val(),
                            $('#t2').val() : $('#p2').val()};

                $.ajax({
                    typeof: "POST",
                    url: '/test.aspx',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: json_obj,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(msg) {
                        alert('Success!');
                    },
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert('Error!');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Type: 1: <input type="text" id="t1" />
        Property 1: <input type="text" id="p1" />

        Type 2: <input type="text" id="t2" />
        Property 2: <input type="text" id="p2" />
        <input type="button" value="Add object!" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(string json)
    {
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObj["json_obj"];
        first = (string)jObj["t1"];
        second = (string)jObj["t2"];
    }

    public string first { get; set; }
    public string second { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Declaration of what object? Post a more detailed description of your error and where you need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the format of your json data is wrong. Try this:

```
var json_obj = "{'" + $('#t1').val() + "' : '" + $('#p1').val() + "', '" + $('#t2').val() + "' : '" + $('#p2').val() + "'}";
```

Comment: That's a string representation of JSON. It's not a JSON _object_,

Comment: or... he could just wrap the json object to JSON.stringify(json_obj). it's a lot safer

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function in your C# code such as:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Test()
 {
   return Json(new {Success = true, CustomJSONAttribute="Whatever You Like"});
 }
```

Then adjust your JQuery ajax to point at Test() and then in your success function you can do:

msg.Success and msg.CustomJSONAttribute

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I have been struggling with this for hours.  I eventually solved my missing parameter issue by ensuring that the JSON object/var in my $.ajax call matched the parameter name in C#.  I honestly couldn't believe that this was the issue.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SetSession(String **json**)
    {
        String s = json;
    }
```

...

```
var json_obj = "{'" + '**json**' + "' : '" + 'the_val' + "'}";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "my_page.aspx/SetSession",
                    data: json_obj,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        alert('SetSession executed.');
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });
```